# PowerShell to post json content as pull request comment body

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to publish a comment to the PR from the sample output file as the comment body. I had difficulties in preserving the human readable format in the body as it was printing it as one line. Now I think I made it to work but still the Invoke-WebRequest is failing with **"innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null".**

I can see that content is formatted correctly in $body but still null message is the error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$JsonContent = Get-Content .\temp.output -Raw
$bodyFromJson = @{"comments"=@{"parrentCommentId"=0;"comment"=$JsonContent;"commentType"="1"};"properties"=@{"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.SupportsMarkdown"=@{"type"="System.Int32";"value"="1"};"status"="1"}}
$body = $bodyFromJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/uri"
$headers = @{
"Content-Type" = "application/json"
"Authorization" = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Now I am getting the below error

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABeBh.png)

**temp.output content is below**

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
~ update in-place

Update will perform the following actions:

# Resource ABC will be updated in-place
~ resource “resource_name” {
endpoint_name = “ABC”
endpoint_type = “xyz”
priority = 2
~ weight = 1 -> 10

custom_header {
name = “host”
value = “host.test.com”
}
}

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please check so that the comment doesnt end up as null in your $body.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include the error text? This would help others to locate your question using a search engine, as well as come up with a useful answer.

Comment: @Nick - Updated the question to include the error.

Comment: @Dan - yes, $body is not null.

Comment: Check te content of $JsonContent

Comment: @Dan, $jsoncontent, $bodyfromjson, $body everything showing the correct and expected values.

Comment: The `temp.output` uses curly 'smaty-quotes' (`“` and `”`). Are you sure these are allowed? What is you change these into straight quotes?

Comment: That didn't do any magic either. Still the same error.

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised you're not running into [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6388).  The workaround mentioned by markekraus in that thread may help.  Also, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36368402/11609403).  PowerShell may be encountering a problem with the web server's response.  Adding `-Verbose` to your `Invoke-WebRequest` line may shed more insights.

Comment: What if you change  one-line JSON format? Kindly check this blog PowerShell Script to call REST API--https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/azure/201/devops-rest-powershell.html If it help in your situation.